# Equations and images not detected in vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes, equation, detect

I am trying to find the type of embedded file that is present on a powerpoint slide. If there are simple excel or visio files, it detects them. I have also other embedded images and equation but the code gives the following error:

Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface

The code is below and the error line is the debugprint line.

```
enter code here

 For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For x = oSl.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set oSh = oSl.Shapes(x)
                Select Case oSh.Type
                Case msoChart, msoEmbeddedOLEObject, msoLinkedOLEObject
                Debug.Print "Slide " & i & " has a " & oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Application.Name & " file"

                End Select
    Next
Next

   Result:
   SLIDE(1): "Slide11"
   #1           "Foot Placeholder 1"    Type:=14 (msoPlaceholder)
   #2           "Title 2"     Type:=14 (msoPlaceholder)
   #3           "Object 3"    Type:=7 (msoEmbeddedOLEObject)
   #4           "Object 4"    Type:=7 (msoEmbeddedOLEObject)
   #5           "Object 5"    Type:=7 (msoEmbeddedOLEObject)
   #6           "Object 10"   Type:=7 (msoEmbeddedOLEObject)
   #7           "Object 11"   Type:=7 (msoEmbeddedOLEObject)
   #8           "Object 15"   Type:=7 (msoEmbeddedOLEObject)

   SLIDE(2): "Slide12"
   #1           "Footer Placeholder 1"      Type:=14 (msoPlaceholder)
   #2           "Title 2"     Type:=14 (msoPlaceholder)
   #3           "Object 4"    Type:=7 (msoEmbeddedOLEObject)
```

Comment: Change your case selector to Case msoChart, msoEmbeddedObject  ... leave out msoLinkedOLEObject. For linked objects, look at oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullname and work out the source app from the extension of the file that that gives you.

Comment: removing the msolinkedoleobject didnt work. still the same error

Comment: Please edit your original post to include the current code. And if possible, post an example file and link to it from here in case someone wants to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

As Steve Rindsberg suggested, you should work with `ShapeObject.LinkFormat.SourceFullName`. Below will list all Shapes in all Slides for Activepresenation. It should help you decide what to do next.

The **[LinkFormat.SourceFullName]** will be appended when available.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListAllShapesType()
    Dim oSlide As Slide, oShp As Shape, i As Long
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Debug.Print "SLIDE(" & oSlide.SlideIndex & "): """ & oSlide.Name & """"
        i = 1
        For Each oShp In oSlide.Shapes
            Debug.Print " #" & i, """" & oShp.Name & """", "Type:=" & WhatShapeType(oShp)
            i = i + 1
        Next oShp
        Debug.Print
    Next oSlide
End Sub

Function WhatShapeType(ShapeObject As Shape) As String
    Dim sType As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case ShapeObject.Type
        Case msoAutoShape: sType = msoAutoShape & " (msoAutoShape)"
        Case msoCallout: sType = msoCallout & " (msoCallout)"
        Case msoCanvas: sType = msoCanvas & " (msoCanvas)"
        Case msoChart: sType = msoChart & " (msoChart)"
        Case msoComment: sType = msoComment & " (msoComment)"
        Case msoContentApp: sType = msoContentApp & " (msoContentApp)"
        Case msoDiagram: sType = msoDiagram & " (msoDiagram)"
        Case msoEmbeddedOLEObject: sType = msoEmbeddedOLEObject & " (msoEmbeddedOLEObject)"
        Case msoFormControl: sType = msoFormControl & " (msoFormControl)"
        Case msoFreeform: sType = msoFreeform & " (msoFreeform)"
        Case msoGroup: sType = msoGroup & " (msoGroup)"
        Case msoInk: sType = msoInk & " (msoInk)"
        Case msoInkComment: sType = msoInkComment & " (msoInkComment)"
        Case msoLine: sType = msoLine & " (msoLine)"
        Case msoLinkedOLEObject: sType = msoLinkedOLEObject & " (msoLinkedOLEObject)"
        Case msoLinkedPicture: sType = msoLinkedPicture & " (msoLinkedPicture)"
        Case msoMedia: sType = msoMedia & " (msoMedia)"
        Case msoOLEControlObject: sType = msoOLEControlObject & " (msoOLEControlObject)"
        Case msoPicture: sType = msoPicture & " (msoPicture)"
        Case msoPlaceholder: sType = msoPlaceholder & " (msoPlaceholder)"
        Case msoScriptAnchor: sType = msoScriptAnchor & " (msoScriptAnchor)"
        Case msoShapeTypeMixed: sType = msoShapeTypeMixed & " (msoShapeTypeMixed)"
        Case msoSlicer: sType = msoSlicer & " (msoSlicer)"
        Case msoSmartArt: sType = msoSmartArt & " (msoSmartArt)"
        Case msoTable: sType = msoTable & " (msoTable)"
        Case msoTextBox: sType = msoTextBox & " (msoTextBox)"
        Case msoTextEffect: sType = msoTextEffect & " (msoTextEffect)"
        Case msoWebVideo: sType = msoWebVideo & " (msoWebVideo)"
        Case Else: sType = ShapeObject.Type & " (Undocumented type!)"
    End Select
    sType = sType & " [" & ShapeObject.LinkFormat.SourceFullName & "]"
    WhatShapeType = sType
End Function
Option Explicit

Sub ListAllShapesType()
    Dim oSlide As Slide, oShp As Shape, i As Long
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Debug.Print "SLIDE(" & oSlide.SlideIndex & "): """ & oSlide.Name & """"
        i = 1
        For Each oShp In oSlide.Shapes
            Debug.Print " #" & i, """" & oShp.Name & """", "Type:=" & WhatShapeType(oShp)
            i = i + 1
        Next oShp
        Debug.Print
    Next oSlide
End Sub

Function WhatShapeType(ShapeObject As Shape) As String
    Dim sType As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case ShapeObject.Type
        Case msoAutoShape: sType = msoAutoShape & " (msoAutoShape)"
        Case msoCallout: sType = msoCallout & " (msoCallout)"
        Case msoCanvas: sType = msoCanvas & " (msoCanvas)"
        Case msoChart: sType = msoChart & " (msoChart)"
        Case msoComment: sType = msoComment & " (msoComment)"
        Case msoContentApp: sType = msoContentApp & " (msoContentApp)"
        Case msoDiagram: sType = msoDiagram & " (msoDiagram)"
        Case msoEmbeddedOLEObject: sType = msoEmbeddedOLEObject & " (msoEmbeddedOLEObject)"
        Case msoFormControl: sType = msoFormControl & " (msoFormControl)"
        Case msoFreeform: sType = msoFreeform & " (msoFreeform)"
        Case msoGroup: sType = msoGroup & " (msoGroup)"
        Case msoInk: sType = msoInk & " (msoInk)"
        Case msoInkComment: sType = msoInkComment & " (msoInkComment)"
        Case msoLine: sType = msoLine & " (msoLine)"
        Case msoLinkedOLEObject: sType = msoLinkedOLEObject & " (msoLinkedOLEObject)"
        Case msoLinkedPicture: sType = msoLinkedPicture & " (msoLinkedPicture)"
        Case msoMedia: sType = msoMedia & " (msoMedia)"
        Case msoOLEControlObject: sType = msoOLEControlObject & " (msoOLEControlObject)"
        Case msoPicture: sType = msoPicture & " (msoPicture)"
        Case msoPlaceholder: sType = msoPlaceholder & " (msoPlaceholder)"
        Case msoScriptAnchor: sType = msoScriptAnchor & " (msoScriptAnchor)"
        Case msoShapeTypeMixed: sType = msoShapeTypeMixed & " (msoShapeTypeMixed)"
        Case msoSlicer: sType = msoSlicer & " (msoSlicer)"
        Case msoSmartArt: sType = msoSmartArt & " (msoSmartArt)"
        Case msoTable: sType = msoTable & " (msoTable)"
        Case msoTextBox: sType = msoTextBox & " (msoTextBox)"
        Case msoTextEffect: sType = msoTextEffect & " (msoTextEffect)"
        Case msoWebVideo: sType = msoWebVideo & " (msoWebVideo)"
        Case Else: sType = ShapeObject.Type & " (Undocumented type!)"
    End Select
    ' Append the LinkFormat detail if available (errors will not affect output)
    sType = sType & " [" & ShapeObject.LinkFormat.SourceFullName & "]"
    WhatShapeType = sType
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. In the above edited post is the result i get in the immediate window. You can see that there are 6 embeddedOleobejects in slide 1 but in actual, 3 of them are images and 3 are equations but it only tells that is a embedded object. no further detail. If I write "ShapeObjectOLEFormat.Object.Application.Name " , it gives me the parent application for eg. if the embedded file is from excel or word or visio. But an occurs when there are embedded equations or embedded images. Is there any way, I could get to know the Allpication they were imported from?

Comment: @MuhammadMustafa You might want to add break point at line `WhatShapeType = sType` and run the code, then observe what's available in **Locals** window and add what works.

Comment: I didnt get you. Can you just elaborate what you mean by break point and Local window?

Comment: In the VBE, go to the line where you want to code to pause during runtime, then click "Debug\Toggle Breakpoint", or press **F9**. To see the Locals window (shows you all the Object's properties), click **View\Locals Window**